# Storm 0.10.0 reuse a topology design?

Tags: apache-storm

Can the following design be accomplished in Storm?

Lets take the wordcount example that is present in the following
https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/starter/WordCountTopology.java
I am changing the word generator spout to a file reader spout

The design for this Word Count Topology is
1. Spout to read file and create sentences line by line
2. Bolt to split sentences to words
3. Bolt to add unique words and give a word and its corresponding count

So in a way the topology is describing the flow a file needs to take to count the unique words it has.

If I have two files file 1 and file 2 one should be able to call the same topology and create two instance of this topology to run the same word count.

In order to track if the word count has indeed finished the instances of word count topology should have a completed status once the file has been processed.

In the current design of Storm, I find that the Topology is the actual instance so it is like a task.

One needs to make two different calls with different Topology names like

for file 1
`StormSubmitter.submitTopology("WordCountTopology1", conf,builder.createTopology());`

for file 2
`StormSubmitter.submitTopology("WordCountTopology2", conf,builder.createTopology());`

not to mention the same upload of the jar using the storm client

`storm jar stormwordcount-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.company.WordCount1Main.App  "server" "filepath1"`

`storm jar stormwordcount-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.company.WordCount2Main.App  "server" "filepath2"`

The other issue is the topologies don't complete once the file is processed. They are alive all the time before we issue a kill on the topology

`storm kill "WordCountTopology"`

I understand that in a streaming world where the messages are coming from a message queue like Kafka there is no end of message but how is that relevant in the file world where the entities/messages are fixed.

Is there an API that does the following?

//creates the topology, this is done one time using the storm to upload the respective jars
`StormSubmitter.submitTopology("WordCountTopology", conf,builder.createTopology());`

Once uploaded the application code just instantiates the topology with the agruments
//creates an instance of the topology and give a status tracker
`JobTracker tracker = StormSubmitter.runTopology("WordCountTopology", conf, args);`

//Can query the Storm for the current job if its complete or not
`JobStatus status = StormSubmitter.getTopologyStatus(conf, tracker);`

Answer (score 0):

For reusing the same topology twice, you have two possibilities:

1) Use a constructor parameter for your file spout and instantiate the same topology with twice with different parameters:

```java
private StormTopology createMyTopology(String filename) {
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.setSpout("File Spout", new FileSpout(filename));
    // add further spouts and bolts etc.
    return builder.createTopology();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String file1 = "/path/to/file1";
    String file2 = "/path/to/file2";
    Config c = new Config();
    if(useFile1) {
        StormSubmitter.submitTopology("T1", c, createMyTopology(file1));
    } else {
        StormSubmitter.submitTopology("T1", c, createMyTopology(file2));
    }
}
```

2) As an alternative, you could configure your file spout in `open()` method.

```java
public class FileSpout extends IRichSpout {
    @Override
    public void open(Map conf, ...) {
        String filenmae = (String)conf.get("FILENAME");
        // ...
    }
    // other methods omitted
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String file1 = "/path/to/file1";
    String file2 = "/path/to/file2";
    Config c = new Config();
    if(useFile1) {
        c.put("FILENAME", file1);
    } else {
        c.put("FILENAME", file2);
    }

    // assembly topology...

    StormSubmitter.submitTopology("T", c, builder.createTopology());
}
```

For you second question: there is no API in Storm that terminates a topology automatically. You could use `TopologyInfo` and monitor the number of emitted tuples of the spout. If it does not change for some time, you can assume that the whole file got read and then kill the topology.

```java
Config cfg = new Config();
// set NIMBUS_HOST and NIMBUS_THRIFT_PORT in cfg
Client client = NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(cfg).getClient();
TopologyInfo info = client.getTopologyInfo("topologyName");
// get emitted tuples...
client.killTopology("topologyName");
```

Comment: Thanks Matthias, thanks for a possible approach, this design of sequential processing would not help as the number of files increases or having to run many files concurrently using the same topology not either file1 or file 2. I guess the files messages too needs to be converted to stream messages and tracking needs to be done independently before converting into streams and after processing the streams the tracking needs to be updated to check for possible end of message.

Comment: Your question ask for something different than you comment ;) However, I am not sure what you mean by "files messages needs to be converted to stream massages" or "tracking needs to be done independently before converting into streams". What so you mean by "tracking need to be updated to check for possible end of message"? Please update your question and describe you setting and what you want to accomplish. Right now, I am a little confused...

Comment: Let me give a shot at what I am trying to acheive. A file can have N messages lets say file 1 has 100 messages file 2 has 200 messages. Like wise there can be M no of files each with N messages. All the files needs to be processed using the same Topology as all the message in all files have the same processing requirement. Right now, due to Storm design, I have to create the same topology with different names for file 1 , file 2 ... and so on. The other issue seems how do I kill the topology once every corresponding file is processed like file 1 after 100 messages and file 2 after 200 message.

Comment: cont..since the topologies do not die after the end of file 1 messages or file 2 messages I am not able to find the end of message. With regard to your comment "get emitted message" to check if the file is processed, how and where do I write this code to check which file is processed? what is the ack and fail method? why can't the topology be killed in the ack or fail method if all the 100 messages of file 1 and 200 messages of file 2 are received in sum total of these two methods. This way I could track all messages of a file processed inside each topology instance.

Comment: You can also process multiple files after each other in a single spout. Just give the whole list of files (as a `List` or `String[]` to your spout). If you do not have any dependencies between your files and can process them in any order, you can also parallelize(with or without parallelism) your spout (or use multiple spouts in a single topology). About "get emitted messages": this code would go to an extra driver program, that monitors the progress of the running topology and kills it if no progress is made any more (assuming that making no progress indicates that all messages got processed)

Comment: Spout.ack() and Spout.fail() are related to fault-tolerance. You could use them to kill a topology -- but I would recommend to use an external program for monitoring. The main problem is, that you don't know how many ack()/fail() calls you need to wait for before killing the topology. Furthermore, you mix two independent things together which does not give a clean code base.

Comment: Thanks Matthias, I too was thinking the same that the processing framework completly misses an important aspect called tracking the progress of processing. Like you said it now needs to go to an external driver that needs to keep track of processing across various worker nodes.  This now needs a technology that can receive and update concurrently across nodes and across multiple threads within the same node. With regard to the solution of multiple files in the spout or multiple spout with multiple spout, this is complicated by a time dimension, which means not all files are present at the ...

Comment: .. time of processing and it keeps arriving at time T1, T2 and so on. So the logic is to build the driver program which inspects each file, create instance of a topology with file identifier, receives the status of each message that is processed and checks to see the initial status and the  processing status; tally's to get processing status for each file. Its better to keep file by file in spout as if you mix multiple files in a spout meta data about each file needs to be present to receive the status back. Considering so much needs to be done, shouldn't this be part of the storm framework

Comment: I see. So I guess my answer stays as is... Start a new topology for each file you detect by your external driver and shut down topologies of number of processes tuples does not change for some duration... Btw: your driver program can be any standalone Java application -- there is no neet to submit a topology via `bin/storm` -- you can submit directly from your external driver program using `StormSubmitter.submitTopology(...)`. You only need to specify JVM flag `-Dstorm.jar=path/to/myJar.jar` -- as you submit the same topology over and over again, this should work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The word count topology mentioned in the post doesn't do justice for the might and power of Storm. Since Storm is a Stream processor, it requires a stream; period. By definition files are files it is static. I empathize with the Storm developers on how can a simple hello world be given to the adoption on how to show case the topology concepts and a non stream technology like file was taken. So to the newbies who are learning Storm which I was at that time, it was a difficult to understand how to develop using the example. The example is just a way to show how Storm concepts work, not a real word application of how files would come or needs to be processed.

So here is the take on how one of the solution could be.

Since topologies run all the time, they can compute the word count for as long as one wants i,e within a file or across all files for any periods of time.

In order to allow for different files to come in, we would need a streaming spout. So naturally you would need a Kafka Message Broker or similar to receive files in a stream. Depending on the size of the file and the restriction that message brokers put namely Kafka which has a 1 MB file restriction, we could pick to send the file itself as the payload or the reference of the file in which case you would need a distributed file system to store the file namely a Hadoop DFS or a NAS.

We then read these files using a Kafka Spout as opposed to FileSpout.

We now have the following issues
1. Word Count Across Files
2. Word Count per File
3. Running Status on the word count till it is processed
4. When do we know if a file is processed or complete

1. Word Count Across Files

Using the example provided, this is the use case the example targets so if we continue to stream the files and in each file we read the lines, split the word and send to other bolts, the bolts would count the words independent of which file it came from.

File1 A quick brown fox jumped ...
File2 Once upon a time a fox ...

Field Grouping
quick
brown
fox
...
Once
upon
fox (not needed as it came in file 1)
...

2. Word Count Per File
   In order to do this, we would now need to put the fields grouping of words to be appended with the fileId. So now the example needs to change to include a fileId for each word it splits.
   So 
   File1 A quick brown fox jumped ...
   File2 Once upon a time a fox ...

So the fields grouping on word would be (canceling the noise words)

File1_quick
File1_brown 
File1_fox

File2_once
File2_upon 
File2_fox

3. Running Status on the word count till it is processed
   Since all these counts are in memory of the bolt and we don't know the EoF there is no way to get the status unless someone peaks into the bolt or we send the counts periodically to another data store where we can query it. This is exactly what we need to do, which is at periodic intervals we need to persist the in-memory bolt counts to a data store like hbase, elastic, mongo db etc
4. When do we know if a file is processed or complete
   Perhaps this is the toughest question to answer in the streaming world, basically the stream processor doesn't know the steam is finished as from its perspective the streams are files coming in and it needs to split each file into words and count in corresponding bolts. So they don't know what has happened before or after it reached each actor.
   This entire thing needs to be done by the app developer.
   One way to do this is when each file is read we count the total words and send a message
   File 1 : Total Words : 1000
   File 2 : Total Words : 2000

Now when we do the word count and find different words per file File1_* the count of individual words and the total words should match before we say a file is complete. All these are custom logic we would need to write before we can say its complete.

So in essential Storm provides the framework to do stream processing in a variety of ways. Its the application developers job to develop with the design that it has and implement their own logic depending on the use case. It doesn't provide application use cases out of the box or a good reference implementation which I think we need to build as its not a commercial product and depends on community to champion.